# How to enable document routing in Transport Client or Node Client

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-storm

I want to use [routing-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html) in Elastic-Search.

But I am not able to find any Java API to enable the same.

I have gone through [link 1](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Does-index-routing-work-with-Transport-Client-td4023125.html) and [link 2](http://blog.sematext.com/2012/05/29/elasticsearch-shard-placement-control/) but none seems to have addressed this.

My code:

```
public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
    this.collector = collector;
    Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                        .put("cluster.name", elasticSearchCluster).build();
    this.client = new TransportClient(settings)
             .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(esHost, esPort));
}

public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
    try {
        String document = tuple.toString();
        byte[] byteBuffer = document.getBytes();
        IndexResponse response = this.client.prepareIndex(indexName, type, id)
                                     .setSource(byteBuffer).execute().actionGet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    collector.ack(tuple);
}
```

Note that I am using TransportClient here as there does not seem to be a good way of using Node-Client with storm but the question is irrespective of that. If there is a way of using Node-Client with routing, please do suggest otherwise TransportClient's routing would also be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are confusing two different "routing" concepts in ES. One is [document routing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html) and the other is [index allocation routing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/shard-allocation-filtering.html) (or "filtering").

The `_routing` field allows you specify the value to be used when indexing each document to determine which shard the document will be indexed on. The other two links you provided refer to an *index-level* (as opposed to *document-level*) setting that determines how the shards of an index are allocated to the various nodes in your cluster.

It sounds like you are trying to do document routing. This can be accomplished in the Java API using the `IndexRequestBuilder` class and the `setRouting(String)` method. Have a look at the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/index/IndexRequestBuilder.java).

There are also some [good code examples here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequestBuilder) which specify the routing field during indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Almost!

you can just replace one line of codes

from

```
    IndexResponse response = this.client.prepareIndex(indexName, type, id)
                                 .setSource(byteBuffer).execute().actionGet();
```

to

```
    String routingValue = "ANY_ROUTING_VALUE_YOU_WANT";
    IndexResponse response = this.client.prepareIndex(indexName, type, id)                              .setSource(byteBuffer).setRouting(routingValue).execute().actionGet();
```

Then your documetns will be stored in a specific shard corresponding to the routing value you provide. In search time, you can provide the same routing value so that your search request hits only one specific shard.